# Linq to Entities 4.0 - Optimized Query and multiple calls to database in a single query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, subquery

Can anyone tell me if the following query calls the database multiple times or just once?

```
var bizItems = new
{
    items = (
        from bl in db.rc_BusinessLocations
        orderby bl.rc_BusinessProfiles.BusinessName
        select new BusinessLocationItem
        {
            BusinessLocation = bl,
            BusinessProfile = bl.rc_BusinessProfiles,
            Products = bl.rc_InventoryProducts_Business
        })
        .Skip(pageSkip).Take(pageSize),

    Count = db.rc_BusinessLocations.Count()
};
```

I really need to get the Count() out of the query and I couldn't find another way to do it so if you have some better optimized code, feel free to share it!

Thanks in advance!

Gwar

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you need a count of all the rc_BusinessLocations in the database, not a count of those put into items correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I should have mentioned that this is to be used for paging so I need a subset for display on the page but the pager component needs to know how many items exist globally (showing items x to y of [total_count] items).
The code above works perfectly but I'm just wondering if I'm making 2 separate calls to the database...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on what you are doing with the `bizItems` variable, because after you've ran just this code, only a `COUNT(*)` query will have ran. This is because the `item` contains an `IQueryable` which is a description of a query (an intent to run), not the result of the operation. The query will only run when you start iterating this query, by using `foreach` or an operator such as `.Count()`. Besides this, the `BusinessProfile` and `Products` properties will probably also contain `IQueryable`s.

So, let's take a look at what you might do with this code:

```
foreach (var item in bizItems.items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.BusinessLocation.City);

    foreach (var profile in item.BusinessProfile)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(profile.Name);
    }

    foreach (var product in item.Products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(product.Price);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(item.Count);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

So, if you ask me again, looking at this code, how many queries will be sent to the database, my answer is: 2 + 2 * the number of items in `bizItems.items`. So the number of queries will be between 2 and (2 + 2 * pageSize).

Comment: Steven,

That's a very informative answer. I wasn't aware of how much the query was being optimized, even after the fact. So basically, if I understand your reply correctly, there's no way to know how many calls will be made to the database unless you know exactly how the (intended) results are being used..

Thanks!

Comment: Had to split my comment in 2..
----
I guess, the only remaining question is: is there a better way to optimize the query I posted? I would love to be able to create temporary variables the same way 'Count(1) as TotalCount' works in SQL. It kind of seems like I just need to embrace Linq and just hope that it does a good job since database calls depend on a mix of query and later use.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gwar: I advice you to try to understand how LINQ works, because you won't have to "just hope that it does a good job". It is probably hard to try to have the `Count` and main result execute in a single database query, however, it is possible to prevent all those 'sub' queries to execute by using anonymous types and the optimizations that LINQ to Entities offers.

Comment: @Gwar: If you find performance too slow, and can't manage to optimize it, post a new question with the query and the usage here on SO. Possibly also include the output of the `DataContext.Log` to your questions. If you formulate your question well, there will be enough people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Scott Guthrie's [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx) on using the LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer.  This will allow you to see exactly the SQL that will be generated from your LINQ statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely result in two calls.